# How Can I Select State According To Country In Cakephp Using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, cakephp

How Can I Select State According To Country In Cakephp Using Ajax?

I want to add state list according to the selected country. For e.g if india

is selected then india States appears in states drop down etc.

Its not working.when i am going to select state according to country.

please help me.below is my coding

in controller

```js
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class VenuesController extends AppController {
public $uses = array('State','Country','Venue','Facility','User','Image');
public $components = array('Custom');
##################add state##############################
   public function state()
    {
 if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
 $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $countryid=$this->request->data('country_id');
    $selectstate = $this->State->find('list', array('fields' => array('state_name'), 'conditions' => array('State.country_id' => $countryid)));
    $this->set('selectbox',$selectstate); 
 //pr($selectstate);
 }
    }
 }
```

```html
in ctp file
<script>
$.noConflict();
</script>
<link href="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT;?>css/jquery.validate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT;?>js/jquery.min.1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT;?>js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT;?>js/jquery.validation.functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="<?php echo HTTP_ROOT;?>css/admin/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 function showFields(id) 
{ 
alert(id);
//alert("hello");
dataString="country_id="+id;
alert(dataString);
  $.ajax({
            url: "venues/state",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString,//alert(data);
   success: function(data)
    {     
     $('#result').html(data);
             },
        });
}
</script>
 
<section  class="content-header">
<h1> Add Venue </h1>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="http://localhost/locatevenue/users"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
  <li class="active">Add Venue</li>
</ol>
</ section>
<!-- Main content -->
<section  class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- left column -->
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash('success_message') ?>
    <div class="col-md-61">
      <!-- general form elements -->
      <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">Add Venue</h3>
        </div>
        <div style="width:49%; float:left;">
          <?php   echo $this->Form->create('Venue' ,array('id' =>'myform' ,'name' => 'myform','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); ?>
          <div class="box-body">
             
           
            <div class="form-group">
              <?php   echo $this->Form->input('country', array('onChange'=>'showFields(this.value)','class'=>'form-control','id' =>'country','type' => 'select','label'=>true,'label'=>'country:','options' => $country ,'empty' => 'Select A Country','required'=>'false'));  ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div id="result">
                <?php  
      echo $this->Form->input('state', array('class'=>'form-control','id' =>'state','type' => 'select','label'=>true,'label'=>'state:','options' => $state ,'empty' => 'Select A State','required'=>'false'));  ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div id="state"></div>-->
               
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: no error message is coming.but state doesnot appear according to country

Comment: when i am going to alert(data); this alert data is not coming

Comment: in controller i have cakephp coding.

Comment: <?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class VenuesController extends AppController {
public $uses = array('State','Country','Venue','Facility','User','Image');
public $components = array('Custom');

   public function state()
    {
 if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
 $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $countryid=$this->request->data('country_id');
    $selectstate = $this->State->find('list', array('fields' => array('state_name'), 'conditions' => array('State.country_id' => $countryid)));
    $this->set('selectbox',$selectstate); 
 //pr($selectstate);
 }
    }
 }

Comment: please paste this code in question and format it so that I can understand..And If you are calling model function then also provide code for model function..

Comment: ok..doing............

Comment: You have to echo your result in php file.. then only it display in the list..

Comment: you first add $this->autoRender = false; in your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action the list only and sent id to the view and generate the options like -

**View file** for `state` action

```
<option value="">Select One</option>
<?php
foreach($selectbox as $key => $value) {
   echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
}
?>
```

Generate the select field with an id -

```
echo $this->Form->input('state', array('class'=>'form-control','id' =>'state','type' => 'select','label'=>true,'label'=>'state:','options' => $state ,'empty' => 'Select A State','required'=>'false'));  ?>
```

Now on the `Ajax success` part -

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "venues/state",
        type: "POST",
        data: dataString,//alert(data);
        success: function(data)
         {     
            $('#state').html(data);
         },
    });
```

Hope it will do the trick.

Comment: here data is not entering into $.ajax({  i think

Comment: Have you tried it? It should send the html of view page to `data`

Comment: i have alert it.but no html of view is coming.might have error in this part.checking it

Answer (score 0):

Please echo your result in controller or model where your getting state list..then try to alert data in success function.
format your code like select dropdown Means like this

```
<option value="<?php echo state_id;?>"><?php echo $state_name;?></option>
```

Make changes according to cake php.